# How to return all the check and unchecked value from a list of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9m2n8n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
I am creating list of check-boxes using the following data objects:

```
data = [
 { Key: "class_id", displayName: "Section ID", enabled: true },
 { Key: "room_l4", displayName: "Location", enabled: false },
 { Key: "section", displayName: "Section", enabled: true },
 { Key: "section_2", displayName: "Section 2", enabled: true },
 { Key: "campus", displayName: "Description", enabled: true }
 ]
```

when user select the checkbox, I want to change the 'enable' from false to true and vice versa. after clicking on submit button I want to console log the data object the way it is now, except the changed value of 'enable' field. For example if user Uncheck the checkbox for data[0].enabled, then my expected result would be:

```
 data = [
 { Key: "class_id", displayName: "Section ID", enabled:false },
 { Key: "room_l4", displayName: "Location", enabled: false },
 { Key: "section", displayName: "Section", enabled: true },
 { Key: "section_2", displayName: "Section 2", enabled: true },
 { Key: "campus", displayName: "Description", enabled: true }
 ]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
myForm: FormGroup
name = 'Angular';
data = [
  { Key: "class_id", displayName: "Section ID", enabled: true },
  { Key: "room_l4", displayName: "Location", enabled: false },
  { Key: "section", displayName: "Section", enabled: true },
  { Key: "section_2", displayName: "Section 2", enabled: true },
  { Key: "campus", displayName: "Description", enabled: true }
  ]
  onSubmit(e){
  console.log(e)
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('valu'),
  });
  }

  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <form  [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngFor="let a of data">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            formControlName="name" 
            (click)="onSubmit()"
            type="checkbox"
            [checked]="a.enabled"
          />
          {{ a.displayName }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Checkboxes are individual form controls, construct your form group with that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You can build a form using a `FormArray` for your data. Listen to changes using `valueChanges`.

component.ts

```js
form: FormGroup

private formControls: {
  data: FormArray;
};

ngOnInit() {
  this.formControls = {
    data: new FormArray(this.data.map(x => {
      return new FormGroup({
        enabled: new FormControl(x.enabled)
      });
    }))
  };

  this.formControls.data.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.data.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.enabled = this.formControls.data.controls[i].get('enabled').value;
    });
  });

  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
}
```

component.html

```html
<form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" formArrayName="data"
    *ngFor="let a of data; index as i">
    <li class="list-group-item" [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>
        <input formControlName="enabled" type="checkbox" />
        {{ a.displayName }}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The initial form array is built from your data array.

The form directives mirror the structure of your form. Notice how `[formGroupName]="i"` binds to the `i`th form group in the array.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-88kjfq

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to simply use `[(ngModel)]` and avoid using forms. just work with `this.data`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ach8xw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html